# Need help going from Excel Array formulas to SQL Join statements

Tags: sql, arrays, excel

Here is the table (new user, can't post images yet):

[image: screenshot]

I've always used Excel, but I'm switching over to SQL due to larger data sets.  To populate CELL G2 in Excel, I would have used something like this:

```
=SUM((A2:A8=E2)*(B2:B8))
```

That gives a value of 141 in Excel for Cell G2.

I figured out how to get this to work in SQL, but I don't exactly understand why this works.  Here's what I used in SQL:

```
SET Table2.total_units_purchased = Table1.some_number
FROM Table2 INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Table1.item
    , SUM(Table1.units_purchased) AS some_number
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY Table1.item
) Table1
ON Table2.item = Table1.item
```

Is the "AS" required before some_number?  This still works for some reason even if I omit "AS".

Am I missing anything here?  Does the order of the tables in the last line of code matter?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: AS in this case is an alias and while good form, it is not required.  order of the ON clause does not matter.

Comment: I was a little confused about "AS" because I originally used to use it to label a column in the results of a query.  I didn't know it could be used to assign values like this.

Comment: Your query is fine. First you sum the units purchased (run the inner query to see its output) then treat this as a derived table (with alias "Table1") and join to it to perform an update.

Comment: Things make A LOT more sense now.  Thank you!  I didn't realize that "Table1" in the first and last two lines was an alias!  I thought I was actually referencing the original Table1, which is why I was confused about how I could reference "some_number" when it never existed in Table1...

Comment: I re-ran the code with a different name for "Table1" in the first and last two lines.  This also explains why I was missing the "AS" in the 2nd to last line.  I didn't know "Table1" was actually an alias there.

Answer (score 1):

Using 'AS' keyword in as an alias is optional, that's why your query still works when you omit the 'AS'.

Secondly, the order of the tables in the last line of code does not matter in this case. The query would work in the same way if your code was `ON Table1.item = Table2.item`. Note that table order matters if you are using left or right outer joins.

In your SQL code you are selecting the 'item' and the 'sum of the units purchased' for that item and you put these data into another table which you rename to Table1 again.

Then, you join two tables, Table2 and new Table1 where their item fields have the same value.

Lastly, you are selecting the 'sum of the units purchased' field and assign it to Table2's total_units_purchased field.

You could have written your SQL query as the following, which does the same thing with your Excel function.

```
select sum(table1.units_purchased)
into table2.total_units_purchased
from table1, table2
where Table2.item = Table1.item
```

Comment: I get an "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'" error when I try to run this.  This seems like a much simpler solution than what I was doing.  I'm not 100% sure how either solution is working right now...need to still wrap my head around SQL language.

Comment: The query above should be working fine without any errors. Which database do you refer to? Oracle, MySQL, ..?